# How can $ zi(e^{iw} + e^{-iw}) = e^{iw} - e^{-iw} $ become $e^{iw}(1-iz) = e^{-iw}(1+iz)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to get from this from:

$$ zi(e^{iw} + e^{-iw}) = e^{iw} - e^{-iw} $$

Into this other form:

$$e^{iw}(1-iz) = e^{-iw}(1+iz)$$

I've tried doing the sums but the answer is nowhere from where I'm trying to get. I've tried as well multiplying by $(iz)^{-1}$ but that got me nowhere as well.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try expanding the product on the left and collecting the terms containing the two different exponential factors on each side.

Comment: Just expand the expression on the left and combine the terms with identical exponent.

Answer (score 2):

It's just moving terms from one side of the equality to the other. We have
$$ zi (e^{iw}+e^{-iw}) = e^{iw}- e^{-iw}$$
$$ zi e^{iw}+ zi e^{-iw} = e^{iw}- e^{-iw}$$
$$ zi e^{iw} - e^{iw} =- zi e^{-iw} - e^{-iw}$$
$$ -(1-zi ) e^{iw}=- (1+zi) e^{-iw} $$
$$ (1-zi ) e^{iw}= (1+zi) e^{-iw} $$